# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement catboost==0.23 Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, catboost

I want to deploy my app on Heroku but it gives this error. I do not know if it is helpful but my python version is 3.9.2

```
here was an issue deploying your app. View the build log for details.

-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> Python app detected
-----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.10.5
       To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> Installing python-3.10.5
-----> Installing pip 22.1.2, setuptools 60.10.0 and wheel 0.37.1
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting anvil-uplink==0.3.40
         Downloading anvil_uplink-0.3.40-py2.py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
       Collecting sklearn==0.0
         Downloading sklearn-0.0.tar.gz (1.1 kB)
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
       Collecting pandas==1.3.3
         Downloading pandas-1.3.3-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (11.5 MB)
       Collecting numpy==1.21.2
         Downloading numpy-1.21.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (15.9 MB)
       Collecting Flask==2.0.2
         Downloading Flask-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
       Collecting gunicorn==20.1.0
         Downloading gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
       ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement catboost==0.23 (from versions: 0.1.1.2, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6)
       ERROR: No matching distribution found for catboost==0.23
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with CatBoost, but [the downloads listed on PyPI for version 0.23](https://pypi.org/project/catboost/0.23/#files) (April, 2020) appear to be built for CPython 2.7, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, and 3.8.

Your application is using Python 3.10:

```
No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.10.5
```

You have two options:

1. Continue to use Python 3.10 and upgrade to a compatible version of CatBoost.

   [Version 1.0.1](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/releases/tag/v1.0.1) (November, 2021) appears to be the oldest compatible version, and the latest version at the time of writing is [version 1.0.6](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/releases/tag/v1.0.6) (May, 2022).

   I *strongly* urge you to update your local Python environment to match.
2. Use an older version of Python on Heroku.

   [Python 3.7 and 3.8 are still supported at the time of writing](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes), but only on the Heroku-18 and Heroku-20 [stacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack). If you are using Heroku-22 you'll have to downgrade your stack.

   You can tell Heroku which version of Python you wish to use by [including a file called `runtime.txt` that contains the Python version in a particular format in the root directory of your project](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes), e.g.

   ```
   python-3.8.13
   ```

   Select a [supported version](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes), create your `runtime.txt` accordingly, commit it, then redeploy.